# Material UI: cannot customize theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the theme of my app (which uses Material UI) as such:

https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#muithemeprovider

**src/index.js:**

```
import App from './App';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: green,
    secondary: green,
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
    <App />
   </MuiThemeProvider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**src/App.js:**

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
class App extends Component {
   ...
}

export default withTheme()(App);
```

However, the default theme color is still showing for me:
[image]

I'm trying to achieve this color theme from Firebase Console:
[image]
Why is it not working?

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
```

Needs to be:

```
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

Comment: awesome, nice find!

Comment: I've been doing just that with the `theme` attribute and I'm still getting purple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `withTheme()` https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#withtheme-component-component

in your `Root` component, you should export:

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default withTheme()(Root);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jee, could you please take a look at modified code above? It's still not working. Thanks

Comment: withTheme is just used to allow access to the theme in your components. Totally not necessary